# 301 url redirect .htaccess in Apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can i direct the search engines from one domain to other domain for better SEO optimization. I want to make 301 redirect from domain.uk to language directory of another domain domain.com/gr
How can to change last line code? Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-old\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example-new.com/gr [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to ask an actual question, not just tell us what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-old\.uk$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example-new.com/gr [R=301,L]
> ```

You've not actually stated the problem you are having. However, if you want to redirect to the same URL-path, but with a `/gr/` path segment prefix (language code) then you are missing a backreference to the captured URL path (otherwise there's no reason to have the capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to begin with).

For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://example-new.com/gr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the value captured by the preceding `(.*)` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-old\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example-new.com/gr%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: If I change the protocol from http to https of the new domain the code - 
RewriteRule ^ http://example-new.com/gr%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END] does it need to change.

Comment: @EmoIT Sorry, I fail to understand what you actually ask in your comment... If you change the protocol to https, then the request gets redirected to the https protocol, sure. Not sure what you mean by "does it need to change".